# Grading an assignment without assigning scores

Tags: word-request

If I say I "grade" an assignment that was handed in by a student, to me it sounds as if that implies:

1. I verify the handed-in assignment for correctness,
2. I assign a score or grade to it.

Is there a term in English that implies only the first, but not necessarily the second? In German, we have the term "korrigieren" for that. To me, "correcting" an assignment sounds more as if the student fixed their mistakes after it was graded.

Comment: What is the output of the process? Is there any kind of information sent back to the students? I note that in your question you use "verify." How about verify?

Comment: Yes, the marked assignment will be returned to the students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I checked the paper, but didn't mark it.

Marking is rather more general then grading.  Grading means assigning a grade to a paper, typically A,B,C grades.  Marking means writing on the paper, so marking can be marking maths work for correctness by "ticking", or marking an essay by writing comments.  Having marked a piece of work a teacher might then determine the score (eg 7/10) and convert that to a grade "B+"

"Grading" is also a term much more common in American English.

In your case it seems that you don't grade, and you don't even mark the work. Instead you just check it.